# How to turn long structured table into wide table for multiple variables without losing MOES

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to do use ACS data to make a simple table comparing median values of people who walked to work compared to median household income. In long form, it includes the MOEs, but then if I use wide format, they MOEs are lost!

Here's the code:

```
ORmhiwalkedtablewide <- get_acs(
  geography = "place",
  state = "OR",
  variables = c(medinc = "B19013_001", 
                medwalked = "B08101_033"),
  output="wide"
  )
```

and the result:

[Long string data, duplicate entries for city, keeps MOEs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlUJf.png)

versus:

```
ORmhiwalkedtablewide <- get_acs(
  geography = "place",
  state = "OR",
  variables = c(medinc = "B19013_001", 
                medwalked = "B08101_033"),
  output="wide"
  )
```

which results in:

[No duplicate cities, but loses MOEs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTCo5.png)

Furthermore, I really only need it for 5 cities, but am lost on how to organize it from there, but was just going to do it manually in excel

Let me know if there's any more information I can offer

Comment: The MOE column in the long data set appears to have the same values as medincM and medwalkedM in the wide data set, and the estimate columns end with E.  This looks like what I'd expect in a wide data set, but maybe I missed the issue?

The two code chunks also appear to be identical and both equal to the wide data screenshot.
  
Filtering to 5 cities can be achieved in multiple ways, including the filter function in the dplyr library with your 5 cities in place of the 2 examples:  dplyr::filter(ORmhiwalkedtablewide, NAME %in% c("Adair Village city, Oregon", "Adams city, Oregon"))

Comment: Hi Hannah Althea, welcome to SO. Please do not add code or error messages as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, add the code text either in a codeblock starting and ending with ```. Also, it will make it much easier to answer your question if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). So run `dput()` on the data you are using e.g. `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df),20)` if your dataset is large, and copy the result into your question. Thanks